# My touchesBegan wont trigger

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, touchesbegan

Hi I have a problem I haven't been able to figure for a couple of days. I have a touchesBegan method that I want to use to tell when someone is tapping a UIImageView so it can move a different UIImageView up and down with NSTimers. For some reason my TouchesBegan wont work, i know that this is the issue because I tested with NSLogs and the results point to the method not being called. Here is my code, THANKS 
P.S. if there is a super quick fix and it makes me look dumb i'm sorry i've only developed for 6 days now.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(flyImageButton.frame, pt)) {

        flying = YES;

        [playerFall invalidate];

        playerFlyUp = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.03 target:self selector:@selector(flyUp) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:playerFlyUp forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (flying == YES) {
        flying = NO;
        [playerFlyUp invalidate];
        [self startFallTimer];
    }
}
```

Here is my .h file for the person who asked...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GameViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel, *coinsLabel;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *flyImageButton, *playerImage, *flyingObject;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;

    int score;
    int coins;

    BOOL flying;

    NSTimer *playerFlyUp, *playerFall, *scoreTimer, *coinsTimer;
}

@end
```

I Have also tried UITouch like so...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];

    //if (CGRectContainsPoint(flyImageButton.frame, pt)) {
    if ([touch view] == flyImageButton) {
        flying = YES;

        [playerFall invalidate];

        playerFlyUp = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.03 target:self selector:@selector(flyUp) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:playerFlyUp forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    }
}
```

What is really confusing to me is how NSLog "Pos 1" never triggers, no matter where I touch...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    //This NSLog never displays leading me to think that my CGPoint isn't the issue...
    NSLog(@"Pos 1");

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(flyImageButton.frame, loc)) {
    //if ([touch view] == flyImageButton) {
        NSLog(@"Pos 2");
        flying = YES;

        [playerFall invalidate];

        playerFlyUp = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.03 target:self selector:@selector(flyUp) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:playerFlyUp forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we look at your .h file please

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have something eating your touches (e.g. button on top of your view)? Also, you should override all 4 touch methods as per apple guidelines if you plan to perform custom touch handling.

Comment: Would a UIScrollView interfere with it? i have a button that triggers the touchesBegan, but it is supposed to execute something on the scrollview

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      UITouch * touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
}
```

Comment: Then where do I use touch? (sorry im new to this)

Comment: how do i use the UITouch you told me to create using that line of code

Comment: Replace your first two lines of code with those 2 lines :) Tell me how it works then.

Comment: ok so you told me to declare the object of UITouch called "touch" now how do I use "touch" because at the moment it sais it's unused and throws a yellow warning. So what i'm trying to ask is, what do I change to use "touch" and how do I add it to my View

Comment: CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:self.view];

Play with classes within the touch method to get the result you want. The code I just gave you will check what coordinates you click, change it to your needs.

Comment: Brendon, I inserted NSLogs to check where the issue is and my touchesBegan doesn't even trigger outside the if statement so something else must be wrong... is there anything else you need to add to a touchedBegan before it will work? like a declaration or alloc/init?

Comment: Are you adding this method to your @interface?

Comment: the touchesBegan? no, but in another project doing practically the same thing I didn't need to. If i need to declare touchesBegan then let me know. This is weird because it works in a different project without touchesBegan in the interface.

Comment: Compare projects until the bug is found, a little hard trying to find something without the full project in front of my face, that's probably your best option.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:nameofyour_imageview];
```

Change this to point your UIImageview not self.view or try tap gesture recognizer

Comment: sorry for being such a noob but how do you do that?

Comment: where is `nameofyour_imageview` enter name of your image view where you want to register touch event. I guess it is `flyImageButton`.

`CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:flyImageButton];`

Comment: When I do that is throws an error stating: "Property 'CGPoint not found on object of type UIImageView *'"

Comment: ok i tried removing the scrollview and that works fine. so the scroll view must have been interfering. I'll investigate! :)

Comment: ok so im 99% sure its a layering issue with my scroll view. the code is fine but I messed around with the xib file and deleting the scrollview fixed it. But i need to scroll view so what should I do to fix this?